# My Bitcoins have been held up in a transaction for 4 days now. I have a time sensitive issue after this

Tags: multibit, unconfirmed-transactions

Anyways, I won't get into the details, but I tried increasing my fee  to the max (.00098 BTC per trans) so getting confirmed would be easier I think.

I know a fair bit about Bitcoin and this has never happened to me. I have $500 in limbo. I've repaired my MultiBit wallet about 10 times already and it currently is locking me out of my money. Very frustrating.

(1) https://blockchain.info/tx-index/1c23609d2828bb631eb0f8c2525d23dab602c0da1403eaa1d0ec4717dfabde1c

(2)https://blockchain.info/tx-index/a1a47f162981791c6365081c40f28ac4fdd2caebde3a68556e425e4e98436eee

Comment: I think i found one solution... im going to try exporting my old wallet to blockchain

Comment: You've described your situation and some common solutions. What's your question? Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406)

Answer (score 1):

Look for "fee per byte" in the blockchain links you provided. Now compare to https://bitcoinfees.21.co/. Bitcoin fee market changes drastically, especially recently with the surge in price. It's a good idea to check the [bitcoinfees.21.co](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/) for how much I should actually use depending on my priority.

Answer (score -2):

Let me know how tricky this is and see if it works. It seems Multibit sets this fee too low and you cannot change it. The only way to avoid it is to send multiple transactions of a lower amount

Comment: -1 "The only way to avoid it is to send multiple transactions of a lower amount." → Since you pay per amount of data, not per value transferred, how would that have any influence on the success? It would just cost more.